# o que @PreAuthorize deveria fazer?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

Eu estou criando um simples `crud` com `spring-mcv` e `spring-security`.

Tudo está rodando perfeitamente

`spring-security.xml`

```
<b:bean id="handlerWeb1" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler">
    <b:property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="permissionEvaluator"/>
</b:bean>
<b:bean id="handlerMethod2" class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
    <b:property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="permissionEvaluator"/>
</b:bean>

<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
    <expression-handler ref="handlerMethod2"/>
</global-method-security>

<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" >
    <expression-handler ref="handlerWeb1" />
    ...
</http>
```

O logger

```
INFO: Using bean 'handlerWeb1' as web SecurityExpressionHandler implementation
INFO: Using bean 'handlerMethod2' as method ExpressionHandler implementation
```

Quando serguinte `methodo` é executado

```
@RequestMapping("/page")
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission('page','list')")
public ModelAndView pages() {

    return modelAndView( ... ));
}
```

Se `hasPermission('page','list')==true` não tem problema.

Se `hasPermission('page','list')==false` o `methodo` ainda executa e renderiza a `view` mas  as `variables`passada para a `view` ficam vazias.

Pergunto:
Quando `hasPermission('page','list')==false`, o que deveira acontecer?

a) redirect to 403

b) processar a `view` com variaveis vazias.

Comment: Você configurou uma página para o 403? Lá na configuração do Spring-Security você deve fazer isso. Assim, quando o acesso for bloqueado, te direciona pra lá. Todo caso, aqui tem um tutorial sobre isso - http://www.jeejava.com/preauthorize-annotation-haspermission-example-in-spring-security/ -